# Ubuntu video player, central european subtitles

Tags: video, subtitle

I am living in Romania, a central european country and I am trying to see a movie with an integrated subtitle . The problem is that the default video player does not display characters like 'ș', 'ț' even though I've tried all the central european encodings. Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VLC can display Romanian diacritics marks if you go to VLC menu - Tools - Preferences - Subtitles and OSD, and choose from Default encoding section **South-Eastern European (latin 10)** .

This won't work for integrated subtitles so you can either choose to download Romanian subtitles and load them over the integrated subtitles or use **ffdshow** codec pack in Windows only to be able to change integrated subtitles default encoding to show Romanian diacritics.

To make sure Romanian diacritics are working 100% in Ubuntu, you should also install TrueType Microsoft fonts. Open a terminal window and type in:

```
             sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

and press YES when prompted to accept EULA for installing MS true fonts or these fonts won't be installed at all.

VLC player will be able to use most of these Microsoft fonts after you reboot the system. I recommend **Comic Sans MS** or **Trebuchet MS** or any other font that includes **MS** in its name. These fonts are compatible with Romanian diacritics, and especially 'ș', 'ț' as mentioned in your post.

So, it is important that you don't forget to also select an adequate font in VLC subtitles menu to make sure that your Romanian subtitles will work 100% in VLC player and also in any other video player with eastern european support for subtitles.